# How to convert all characters to their html entity equivalent using PHP

Tags: php, string, utf-8, encode, html-entities

I want to convert this `hello@domain.com` to

```
&#104;&#101;&#108;&#108;&#111;&#064;&#100;&#111;&#109;&#097;&#105;&#110;&#046;&#099;&#111;&#109;
```

I have tried:

```
url_encode($string)
```

this provides the same string I entered, returned with the @ symbol converted to `%40`

also tried:

```
htmlentities($string)
```

this provides the same string right back.

I am using a UTF8 charset. not sure if this makes a difference....

Comment: ley I deleted my answer because I realized it is no good. (Thanks Artefacto) however, this is not really sufficient protection against spam bots....

Comment: I am aware that it's not completely foolproof, however I have had good results using this feature in the past, encoding my email address using online services. I'm now trying to build it into a CMS I am building.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Here it goes (assumes UTF-8, but it's trivial to change):

```
function encode($str) {
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str , 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8'); //big endian
    $split = str_split($str, 4);

    $res = "";
    foreach ($split as $c) {
        $cur = 0;
        for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
            $cur |= ord($c[$i]) << (8*(3 - $i));
        }
        $res .= "&#" . $cur . ";";
    }
    return $res;
}
```

**EDIT** Recommended alternative using [`unpack`](http://php.net/unpack):

```
function encode2($str) {
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str , 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
    $t = unpack("N*", $str);
    $t = array_map(function($n) { return "&#$n;"; }, $t);
    return implode("", $t);
}
```

Comment: It's not necessary to print $cur as unsigned when converting to a string in `$res .= "&#" . $cur . ";";` because the range of unicode characters doesn't go that far. However, if you have an invalid UTF-8 sequence, this could give negative values (I don't know if mb_convert_encoding validates the range).

Comment: This is a brilliant answer for 3 reasons: 1. I couldn't have thought of it myself. 2. Is elegant, and works well, 3.I have learnt a lot of good stuff from it. Thanks.

Comment: Your closure in the 2nd version requires PHP 5.3. For pre 5.3, you can pass a string instead, for example `'encoded_str'`, and then have a function that does what the closure does: `function encoded_str($n) { return "&#$n;"; }`. Less elegant, but backward compatible.

Comment: Artefacto, would you be able to convert it back to the original string? with pack?

Comment: @Artefacto very nice answer. it also helps me. thanks.

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<mb_strlen($in);$i++) @$out.='&#'.mb_ord(mb_substr($in,$i,1),'UTF-8').';'; return $out;` may you add a tiny version too

Answer (score 11):

Much easier way to do this:

```
function convertToNumericEntities($string) {
    $convmap = array(0x80, 0x10ffff, 0, 0xffffff);
    return mb_encode_numericentity($string, $convmap, "UTF-8");
}
```

You can change the encoding if you are using anything different.

- Fixed map range. Thanks to Artefacto.

Comment: Nice, I haven't tested, but I suppose you also have to change the map to cover all the unicode characters.

Comment: probably something like `$convmap = array(0x000000, 0x10ffff, 0, 0xffffff);` (untested)

Comment: The convmap in this comment works: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-encode-numericentity.php#88586

Comment: This answer is so simple, and it works well for my application. In order to answer the question, `$convmap` should include normal alphanumeric characters, but not whitespace or line carriages, so `$convmap = array( 0x21, 0x10ffff, 0, 0xffffff, );` may be more applicable. It may also be beneficial to pass the string through a `html_entity_decode` function call, in order to prevent accidental double-encoding of entities.

Comment: For some reason this solution just outputs the non-encoded characters. @Artefacto 's answer works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
function uniord($char) {

     $k=mb_convert_encoding($char , 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');

     $k1=ord(substr($k,0,1));

     $k2=ord(substr($k,1,1));

     $value=(string)($k2*256+$k1);

     return $value;

}
```

the above function works for 1 character but if you have a string you can do like this

```
$string="anytext";

$arr=preg_split(//u,$string,-1,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

$temp=" ";

foreach($arr as $v){

    $temp="&#".uniord($v);//prints the equivalent html entity of string

}
```