# PHP: convert all characters to HTML entities

Tags: php

How to convert all characters in a string to HTML entities?

htmlentities() doesn't work for characters like ćĆČčŠšĐđŽž

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no (named) entities for those characters.

You can see the list [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/sgml/entities.html). If you want to convert to numerical entities, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005116/how-to-convert-all-characters-to-their-html-entity-equivalent-using-php/3005240#3005240).

Comment: Your recommended alternative function encode2() produces the following error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION, expecting ')' on the line where the array_map is called

Comment: @A-OK It's written for PHP 5.3.

Answer (score 8):

```
<?php

function encode($string) {
    return mb_encode_numericentity($string, array(0x000000, 0x10ffff, 0, 0xffffff), 'UTF-8');
}

echo encode('ćĆČčŠšĐđŽž');
```

Result is `&#263;&#262;&#268;&#269;&#352;&#353;&#272;&#273;&#381;&#382;`

Comment: damn! after searching for hours, your answer saved me :)

Comment: This is great! Here’s another method FWIW https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42124369/php-obfuscating-mailto-in-source-with-htmlentities/42124616#42124616

Answer (score 2):

The character code of "ć", is 263, which as an HTML entity is `&#263;`, and so forth.

Comment: Convert first using htmlentities, then convert any characters which are outside the ASCII range in a second pass using `preg_replace_callback` and the regex `"/[^\x00-\x7F]/"`.

Answer (score 2):

It's widely known that some characters are not encoded with `htmlentities();`.

If you look at the [docs](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php), there are some posts with character maps you can use with `str_replace()`