# php obfuscating mailto in source with htmlentities()

Tags: php, html-entities

I am attempting to display email addresses on a page that function normally in a browser, but are obfuscated in code to hopefully get at least some spam bots to ignore them.

I have this test code:

```
<?php
$email = "fake@test.com";
$mailto = "mailto:" . $email;
?>
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>
<body>
<p>PHP: <a href="<?php echo htmlentities($mailto); ?>"><?php echo htmlentities($email); ?></a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>MANUAL: <a href="&#109;&#x61;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#x6f;&#58;&#102;&#x61;&#x6b;&#101;&#x40;&#x74;&#101;&#x73;&#x74;&#46;&#x63;&#111;&#x6d;">&#x66;&#97;&#107;&#x65;&#64;&#116;&#x65;&#x73;&#116;&#46;&#99;&#x6f;&#x6d;</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Both links look and work fine on the page, but only the 'manual' one is encoded.

I'm getting conflicting information from php.net on how htmlentities works.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

The documentation states that "all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities." Since all letters in the alphabet HAVE equivalents, I expect every single char to be converted. But in the examples on that page, it demonstrates that basic letters do not get converted.

Further, when I view the source on that page, it does not appear that the php code has worked at all. My expectation is that both links appear the same in the code. Here is the results of 'view source'.

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /></head>
<body>
<p>PHP: <a href="mailto:fake@test.com">fake@test.com</a></p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>MANUAL: <a href="&#109;&#x61;&#105;&#108;&#116;&#x6f;&#58;&#102;&#x61;&#x6b;&#101;&#x40;&#x74;&#101;&#x73;&#x74;&#46;&#x63;&#111;&#x6d;">&#x66;&#97;&#107;&#x65;&#64;&#116;&#x65;&#x73;&#116;&#46;&#99;&#x6f;&#x6d;</a></p>
</body>
</html>
```

So it looks like htmlentities() isn't doing anything at all. Not even encoding the '@'.

Should I be adding some flags? 
Is there a better way to do this? 
If I am successful will this even work against the bots or am I wasting my time?

Comment: `all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents` means characters that have shorthand, ie, a `>` is ASCII 62, so it could be `&#62;`, but it also has the shorthand `&gt;` (greater than) so that would get converted. But the `@` symbol, ASCII 64, only has `&#64;`, there is no shorthand like `&at;` so it won't get converted. Same goes for letters and most other characters.

Comment: FWIW here’s another good solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720826/php-convert-all-characters-to-html-entities/32997549#32997549

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The misunderstanding may be from http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

> This function is identical to htmlspecialchars() in all ways, except with htmlentities(), all characters which have HTML character entity equivalents are translated into these entities.

What it really means from http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php

> Certain characters have special significance in HTML, and should be represented by HTML entities if they are to preserve their meanings.

`htmlspecialchars()` encodes: `&`, `"`, `'`, `<` and `>`. Check:

```
print_r(get_html_translation_table(HTML_SPECIALCHARS));
```

`htmlentities()` encodes more characters, but only *characters* that *have special significance in HTML*. Check:

```
print_r(get_html_translation_table(HTML_ENTITIES));
```

You might look at something like this.  I checked it in a link and it worked as expected:

```
$result = preg_replace_callback('/./', function($m) {
                                           return '&#'.ord($m[0]).';';
                                       },
                                       'mailto:fake@test.com');
```

This replaces each character in a string with `&#` then the ASCII value of the character and then `;`

Comment: So basically htmlentities encodes everything except the things I want it to. Sounds like I'll have to write my own function to do this.

Comment: Yes, and to obfuscate the way you want will render the link inoperable.  So you will probably need an `onclick()` JavaScript function to de-obfuscate it.

Comment: Actually the links work fine when obfuscated. If you test the code as posted above the "manual" link, which is obfuscated, works perfectly. (It surprised me too.)

Comment: Thanks, that's a good start although I seem to be having some issues getting to to display as encoded. I think we've exhausted the limits of this question as asked so I'm going to accept this and possible ask a new one if I can't get this working right.