# Attempting to convert Latin characters using htmlentities

Tags: php, encoding, html-entities

I'm attempting to html encode various names, which are from all over the world. The system this is eventually going into cannot handle the raw characters itself, so I have to encode them first. htmlentities is working properly in 99% of cases, but I've come upon an exception and cannot make it work (I've tried every encoding option PHP lists). The characters in question are both latin (`Ş` and `ş`). Any suggestions on how to handle these exceptions? I'm using laravel, code below.

```
@foreach ($names as $name)
    {{ htmlentities($name) }}</br>
@endforeach
```

Comment: What exactly happens in this case?

Comment: All characters in the field are properly converted to their corresponding html code, except for the characters listed above, those characters are not changed at all

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP: convert all characters to HTML entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6720826/php-convert-all-characters-to-html-entities)

Comment: You may have fun for such project, but since a lot of years html (and so web) is UTF-8. Not raw, but a well known encoding that every browser can parse, and with less problems then htmlentities (which are very limited, especially the portable one). So keep things simple. Use UTF-8 in your files and in web (Content). Do not over-complicate things, we are no more on the 90s (and disco is no more a thing).

Comment: "The system this is eventually going into cannot handle the raw characters itself" - Have you identified specific characters that cannot be handled by this system, or do you know the specific encoding of this system? Instead of just trying to encode specific characters, it might be better to frame this as "System XYZ needs ABC encoding".

Answer (score 0):

The htmlentities() function is based on ISO-8859-1 characters table as default.
You will have to give the encoding as an argument like this :

```
htmlentities($name, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8')
```

You can choose which encoding you want in the list of the supported charset into the documentation.

Source : https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php