# PHP autoconverts the special character?

Tags: php, file-rename

I have one directory listing code where I am listing all files in specific directory. the file name has one contains specific character other than a-z and 0-9. its like small "i" without dot above "i". The file name is : "ClrmamePro Kullanımı English.mp4" . Look at the "Kullanımı" and "English". you can see the difference between "i" and "ı".

Now the problem is that when I do directory listing php automatically converts letter "ı" to "i" and hence at the time of performing rename I get error

```
rename(E:/workspace/project/ClrmamePro Kullanimi English.mp4,
E:/workspace/project/movie_11.mp4) [<a href='function.rename'>function.rename</a>]: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I have a regular expression to correct the file name but as PHP automatically converts "ı" to "i", I am not able to catch it.

the code for directory listing is as below

```
function getDirectoryListing($directory) {
    // create an array to hold directory list
    $results = array();
    // create a handler for the directory
    $handler = opendir($directory);
    // open directory and walk through the filenames

    while ($file = readdir($handler)) {
        // if file isn't this directory or its parent, add it to the results
        if (strpos($file,'.') !== 0) {
            $results[] = $file;
        }
    }

    closedir($handler);
    // done!
    return $results;
}

echo '<pre>';
print_r(getDirectoryListing('movies'));
echo '</pre>';
```

The o/p i am getting is as below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => ClrmamePro Kullanimi English.mp4
    [1] => Download Gears of War 3 - eSoftZone.webm
    [2] => Facebook_ Science and the Social Graph.MP4
)
```

see the first file at index 0. the actual file name in my directory is

```
ClrmamePro Kullanımı English.mp4
```

Comment: You need to show the code you use.

Comment: there is only directory listing code. Nothing more than that

Comment: if you realy want HELP then you HAVE to show SOME code, otherwise how would you expect us to help you ?

Comment: Hey guys. Now I have provided you all the details of my problem. Than you. Please help...

Comment: are you sure it is php converting the characters, not your browser?

Comment: The `rename` function is looking for a file in `E:/workspace/project/ClrmamePro Kullanimi English.mp4`. Does this file actually exist? Based on your code, shouldn't it be in the `movies` directory: `E:/workspace/project/movies/ClrmamePro Kullanımı English.mp4`?

Comment: Yes, i have checked it in chrome and internet explorer too.

Comment: @creemama, i added sample code. the path provided is correct. Other files are listed well. File really exist. The actual file name i have mentioned in the question.

Comment: Have you tried checking for existence using `file_exists` on each file in the array? Does PHP report that each file exists? `echo '<pre>'; $listing = getDirectoryListing('movies'); foreach ($listing as $file) { echo "$file "; if (file_exists('movies/' . $file)) { echo "exists.\n"; } else { echo "does not exist.\n"; } } echo '</pre>';`

Comment: @creemama, Hey your code helped me. But it just don't display that special character file in my list. it good, but it will confuse end user that why file is not being displayed?

Comment: I was able to display the special characters using the solution found at ["How to convert all characters to their html entity equivalent using PHP"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005116): `encode2($file)`.

Comment: i tried it but, it did not worked for me. @creemama thank you for your time. can you please, copy above code. keep file name as mentioned as me and, please let me know?

Answer (score 0):

For each file in the `movies` directory, the following code snippet outputs the filename and whether the file exists or not. The displayed filename is encoded to display special characters correctly.

The `encode` method converts all characters in the string `"$file "` to HTML entities. The method is a slightly modified version from the solution in the Stack Overflow article ["How to convert all characters to their html entity equivalent using PHP."](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3005240/788324) The solution found in the article did not work on my PHP server, so I moved `prependAmpersandAndPound` outside the function.

```
// https://stackoverflow.com/a/3005240/788324
function prependAmpersandAndPound($n) {
    return "&#$n;";
}
function encode($str) {
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str , 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
    $t = unpack("N*", $str);
    $t = array_map(prependAmpersandAndPound, $t);
    return implode("", $t);
}

echo "<pre>\n";
$listing = getDirectoryListing('movies');
foreach ($listing as $file) {
    echo "\"" . encode($file) . "\" ";
    if (file_exists('movies/' . $file)) {
        echo "exists.\n";
    } else {
        echo "does not exist.\n";
    }
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Mimicking your setup, the code snippet above outputs:

**HTML Source:**

```
<pre>
"&#68;&#111;&#119;&#110;&#108;&#111;&#97;&#100;&#32;&#71;&#101;&#97;&#114;&#115;&#32;&#111;&#102;&#32;&#87;&#97;&#114;&#32;&#51;&#32;&#45;&#32;&#101;&#83;&#111;&#102;&#116;&#90;&#111;&#110;&#101;&#46;&#119;&#101;&#98;&#109;" exists.
"&#67;&#108;&#114;&#109;&#97;&#109;&#101;&#80;&#114;&#111;&#32;&#75;&#117;&#108;&#108;&#97;&#110;&#305;&#109;&#305;&#32;&#69;&#110;&#103;&#108;&#105;&#115;&#104;&#46;&#109;&#112;&#52;" exists.
"&#70;&#97;&#99;&#101;&#98;&#111;&#111;&#107;&#95;&#32;&#83;&#99;&#105;&#101;&#110;&#99;&#101;&#32;&#97;&#110;&#100;&#32;&#116;&#104;&#101;&#32;&#83;&#111;&#99;&#105;&#97;&#108;&#32;&#71;&#114;&#97;&#112;&#104;&#46;&#77;&#80;&#52;" exists.
</pre>
```

**Displayed in a Browser:**

```
"Download Gears of War 3 - eSoftZone.webm" exists.
"ClrmamePro Kullanımı English.mp4" exists.
"Facebook_ Science and the Social Graph.MP4" exists.
```