# Percent-encoding entire PHP string into numbered ASCII values for obfuscation

Tags: php, html, url, obfuscation, percent-encoding

I'd like to somehow obscure the contents of `$url = "http://blah.somedomain.com/contents/somefolder/somefile.htm";` so I can use them for links but so that the URLs are not easily read by humans when looking at the page source. The obfuscated URL still needs to work in a browser when clicking on it though so other methods of obfuscation that I've looked at are no good.

What we're after is e.g. `$obscureurl = "%3A%2F%2F"`...etc

Any ideas? Thanks.

---

**Edit:** Thanks for suggestions so far, but to clarify, I should have said that I'm not after encoding into HTML entities (the # values), I'm after [Percent-encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) (hex values in ASCII).

For example, to change `hello@me.com` into: `%68%65%6c%6c%6f%40%6d%65%2e%63%6f%6d`

ASCII table is here for the hex of each letter and symbol: http://ascii.cl/

Is this kind of complete conversion possible with PHP? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert all characters to their html entity equivalent using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005116/how-to-convert-all-characters-to-their-html-entity-equivalent-using-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$url = '..';
$encoded = join(array_map(function ($byte) { return "%$byte"; }, str_split(bin2hex($url), 2)));
```

That's essentially the entire encoding mechanism. Take the raw bytes in hex (`bin2hex`), `2` characters per byte, and prepend a `%`.

Not that this will really do a whole lot for obfuscation. The browser may indeed not even display it in its encoded form, and even search engines may display only the decoded form. Further, you're still producing a canonical URL. It doesn't matter what exactly that URL contains; if people have a link to it, they have a link to it, regardless of how human readable that link may or may not be.

Comment: How could this be modified to return a string instead of an array? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can see 2 easy ways to achieve this:

- Replace every character of your link by its html entity (see [How to convert all characters to their html entity equivalent using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005116/how-to-convert-all-characters-to-their-html-entity-equivalent-using-php))
- Use some kind of ids and save the matching url in your DB: (something like `http://example.com/redirect/412`)