# Convert Hindi text into html entities code through php

Tags: php

i want to convert some hindi string into html entities through php

like

```
$message = "आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह गए";

$message_convert = SomeKindOfunctionOrProcess($message);

echo $message_convert;

// output : &#2310;&#2319;&#32;&#2341;&#2375;&#32;&#2346;&#2352;&#2381;&#2351;&#2335;&#2325;&#44;&#32;&#2326;&#2369;&#2342;&#32;&#2361;&#2368;&#32;&#2348;&#2361;&#32;&#2327;&#2319;
```

i hope you understand what i want. i can process the output string further in my project. but i have no idea how to convert this from given hindi string directly into variable `$message`

**Edit :**

```
<?php

$message = file_get_contents("hindi.txt");

echo $message;

$message_convert = SomeKindOfunctionOrProcess($message);

file_put_contents("ot1.txt", $message_convert);

?>
```

there is a content(string) `आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह गए` in file `hindi.txt`

and i want output string `&#2310;&#2319;&#32;&#2341;&#2375;&#32;&#2346;&#2352;&#2381;&#2351;&#2335;&#2325;&#44;&#32;&#2326;&#2369;&#2342;&#32;&#2361;&#2368;&#32;&#2348;&#2361;&#32;&#2327;&#2319;` in file `ot1.txt` which is the html entities of given string

Comment: Can you please elaborate on this point - `i have no idea how to convert this from given hindi string directly into variable $message`. This line is bit unclear.

Comment: Have you tried any of the standard HTML-encoding functions in PHP? If not, why not? If so, why aren't they sufficient? Why do you need your perfectly fine string in HTML-gobbledygook to begin with?

Comment: i have tried a lot but couldn't succeed. i don't want to show anything on browser i need to convert a hindi string to html entities string. i am elaborate my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the function [htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php). With this function you can convert characters to html entities. It supports getting character set. So you can make htmlentities to convert UTF-8 characters to entities. The `ENT_QUOTES` means that this function must encode quotations. You can check the documentation for further information.

Your code can be changed like this:

```
<?php

$message = "आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह गए";

$message_convert = htmlentities($message,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");

echo $message_convert;

?>
```

P.S. If you want to convert all characters to html entities you can try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3005240/565286). So your code might be something like this:

```
function encode2($str) {
    $str = mb_convert_encoding($str , 'UTF-32', 'UTF-8');
    $t = unpack("N*", $str);
    $t = array_map(function($n) { return "&#$n;"; }, $t);
    return implode("", $t);
}

$message = "आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह गए";
$message_convert = encode2($message); 
echo $message_convert;
```

Comment: Not resolved i am using this code `<?php

$message = file_get_contents("hindi.txt");

echo $message;

$message_convert = htmlentities($message,ENT_QUOTES,"UTF-8");

file_put_contents("ot1.txt", $message."\n".$message_convert);

?>` output is same as input

Comment: @SatishSharma I think this might help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005116/how-to-convert-all-characters-to-their-html-entity-equivalent-using-php

Comment: thanks bro. its quite good. i have tried one alternative. i will also share that with you as ans.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to just echo

```
$message = "आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह गए";
```

$message variable you can set

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
```

This meta value in head section.

or you can set content type in your php script

```
header( 'Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8' );
```

Comment: he want to convert some hindi string into html entities. not to display

Comment: okay for characters to HTML entities you can do 

$message = "आए थे पर्यटक, खुद ही बह गए";
echo htmlentities($message);

Comment: @SajithaNilan you are right. i want to convert a hindi string format to html entities string format not to display. have you any suggestion

Comment: I thinhk you have to create a converter yourself

Comment: @SajithaNilan thanks !. i have tried and created some customized code.

Answer (score 0):

thanks to all for giving me your valuable time. i have also tried an alternative which i want to share with all of you. but i recommend the answer of `@Amir`

```
function encode ($data)
{
    $html = preg_replace("/([\\xC0-\\xF7]{1,1}[\\x80-\\xBF]+)/e", 'b_utf8_to_html("\\1")', $data);

    $html_convert = "";

    $code = false;
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($html); $i++)
    {
        if($html[$i]=='&' && $html[$i+1]=='#')
            $code = true;


        if($code)
            $html_convert .= $html[$i];
        else        
            $html_convert .= b_utf8_to_html($html[$i]);

        if($code===true && $html[$i]==';')
            $code = false;              
    }

    return $html_convert;
}



 function b_utf8_to_html ($data)
{
    $ret = 0;
    foreach((str_split(strrev(chr((ord($data{0}) % 252 % 248 % 240 % 224 % 192) + 128) . substr($data, 1)))) as $k => $v)
        $ret += (ord($v) % 128) * pow(64, $k);
    return "&#$ret;";
}
```