# PHP - Convert Non-ASCII Characters to hex Entities Without mbstring

Tags: php, unicode, html-entities

I'd like to convert any Unicode string to hex HTML entities, except for ASCII Characters. So a string like:

`Text goes here. Here's だ and here's ã.`

gets converted to

`Text goes here. Here's &#12384 and here's &#227.`

For reference, this question has a function that converts all characters to numerical entities, but it requires mbstring which I cannot use (I also can't use any features past PHP 5.3.10). [How to convert all characters to their html entity equivalent using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005116/how-to-convert-all-characters-to-their-html-entity-equivalent-using-php/3005240#3005240)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THIS IS NOT MY CODE.

I did a simple Google check using "php convert unicode to html" and found this:

https://af-design.com/2010/08/17/escaping-unicode-characters-to-html-entities-in-php/

Which had this:

```
function unicode_escape_sequences($str)
{
 $working = json_encode($str);
 $working = preg_replace('/\\\u([0-9a-z]{4})/', '&#x$1;', $working);
 return json_decode($working);
}
```

That web page also had a lot of other examples on it but this one looked like what you were looking for.

Comment: Strangely, this doesn't seem to work for me. It fails at `json_encode`, I get the `JSON_ERROR_UTF8` error from here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-last-error.php

I'm not sure why though; I tested it in this sandbox and `json_encode` seems to work: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e119287c5a497f8d21c3d19395defec6d2378d76

Comment: Nevermind, I was just mixing up some of my variable names. This works! Thanks!

Comment: Note (a) the `json_encode` will also be adding backslashes to quotes, newlines etc (b) this fails for characters outside the Basic Multilingual Plane as they'll come up as two surrogate `\u` sequences where HTML uses one character reference.

Comment: This function **coverts strings to hex entities** and therefore does *not* answer this question which asks for *numeric entities*.

Comment: Here is the person's original request: "I'd like to convert any Unicode string to hex HTML entities, except for ASCII Characters." Note he says hex . The problem here is that you can not mix the two (ASCII & hex) easily because all functions handle the entire string. Thus it all comes out as hex or whate4ver. If he wants this, I would suggest: To the ICONV() function in PHP plus the" ResourceBundle::getLocales()" function so he can convert them to whatever locale works for him/her. :-)